# How to access source widget's value in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a generic server handler for textboxes which highlights the text when the textbox gains focus:

```
function onFocusHighlight(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var widget = app.getElementById(e.parameter.source);
  var widgetValue = e.parameter.widgetName; // how can I get widgetName from source???  
  widget.setSelectionRange(0, widgetValue.length);  
  return app;
}
```

Can I determine widgetValue from e.parameter.source?

Answer (score 0):

`var widget = app.getElementById(e.parameter.source).setName("widgetName")`

Then get widgetValue:

`var widgetValue = e.parameter.widgetName`

Check https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp for usage of `setName`.

Comment: Clever, but this approach doesn't actually work in practice. It seems that I need the actual name passed in.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that as long as `widgetName` and `widgetId` are the same I can determine `widgetValue` as follows:

```
function onFocusHighlight(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var widgetId = e.parameter.source;
  var widgetName = widgetId; // name MUST match id to retrieve widget value      
  var widgetValue = e.parameter[widgetName]; // not sure why this syntax works???

  var widget = app.getElementById(widgetId);  
  widget.setSelectionRange(0,widgetValue.length);  

  return app;
}
```

My only issue now is understanding how/why the `e.parameter[widgetName]` syntax actually works. It would also be great to have a solution which doesn't rely on `widgetName` and `widgetId` being the same value.

Answer (score 0):

**Just a suggestion** following your own answer :

You could probably make it work by having a conversion table somewhere that gets the widgets name from their ID.

For example you could define :

```
  ScriptProperties.setProperties({'widgetID1':'Name1','widgetID2':'name2'},true)
```

and then

```
 widgetvalue = e.parameter[ScriptProperties.getProperty(e.parameter.source)]
```

I didn't test this code but it seems logical ;-), tell me if it doesn't (I don't have time to test it now)

**EDIT :** works as expected, here is a [test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dHBzVkR3Y2xQemhpTlRUV0h0RklLRFE) to show the result, test code below.

```
function Test(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('test');
  app.add(app.createLabel('Type anything in upper textBox and then move your mouse over it...'))
  var p = app.createVerticalPanel()
  var txt1 = app.createTextBox().setId('txt1').setName('Name1').setValue('value in TextBox1')
  var txt2 = app.createTextBox().setId('txt2').setName('Name2').setValue('waiting to mouseOver textBox1')
  p.add(txt1).add(txt2)
  app.add(p)
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('mouseOver').addCallbackElement(p);
  txt1.addMouseOverHandler(handler); 
  ScriptProperties.setProperties({'txt1':'Name1','txt2':'Name2'},true);//save the name, only txt1 will be used here  
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
ss.show(app)
}

function mouseOver(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var widget = app.getElementById(e.parameter.source);
  var widgetValue = e.parameter[ScriptProperties.getProperty(e.parameter.source)]; // ScriptProperties knows the Widget's name 
  app.getElementById('txt2').setValue(widgetValue) ;// Use the other widget to show result
  return app;
}
```